# Need to understand behaviors of printf

Tags: c

1)

```
char* fun()
{
  return "awake";
}
int main()
{
  printf("%s",fun()+ printf("I see you"));
  return 0;
}
```

output :: I see youee you

```
int main()
{
  printf("%s",5+printf("I see you"));
  return 0;
}
```

output :: Runtime crashing

1) Why both scenario as different behaviour?

2) can anyone explain why "awake" is not printed in first PRINTF?

3) is scenario 1 is depend on the compiler?

Comment: Why would you expect both to have the same behaviour?

Comment: @Marged No, I don't think so. It is a string literal.

Comment: @juanchopanza But string returned by function is ignored .

Comment: @ameyCU No, it isn't. It is used in an expression.

Comment: @juanchopanza it seems my c got a little bit rusty ;-)

Comment: @ameyCU - The function `fun()` returns an address, which then has the return value of `printf()` added to the address.  That resulting address is then interpreted by the outer `printf()` as the address of a NUL-terminated string.  And in this case the address just happens to point in the middle of the `"I see you"` string.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ohh,  okay . So just pure luck that string printed is at that address .

Comment: i asked valid question why my reputation -8,

Comment: i want ask more question but its blocked to ask any question

Comment: @AndrewHenle
i got this answer from after some research 

The function fun() returns pointer to char. Apart from printing string “I see you”, printf() function returns number of characters it printed(i.e. 9). The expression [fun()+ printf(“I see you”)] can be boiled down to [“awake” + 9] which is nothing but base address of string literal “awake” displaced by 9 characters. Hence, the expression [“awake” + 9] returns junk data when printed via %s specifier till it finds ‘\0′.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
  printf("%s",fun()+ printf("I see you"));
```

adds the result of `fun()` (the address of your `"awake"` string literal) to the result of calling `printf()`, which is the integer value `9`, the number of characters printed.  That is a character address plus an integer offset - perfectly legal - and it just happens to be several characters into the `"I see you"` string literal, so it then prints out the end of the `"I see you" string.

This

```
  printf("%s",5+printf("I see you"));
```

tries to print as a NUL-terminated string whatever is at the at the virtual memory address `14`, which probably isn't even mapped into the process address space.